# Video plays at different speed from other apps

Tags: lightworks

I've been working on a video production on my Linux PC and decided to kick it over to my newer Mac to take advantage of faster hardware.  I've already noted the in and out times for the various shots that I want to sequence into my finished video.  On the linux machine I was doing everything using `ffmpeg` on the command line.  On the Mac I'm trying out Lightworks.

The times I've noted for my project don't correspond to the proper frames in Lightworks.  When I play the video in `mplayer` or in Final Cut Pro on the Mac, the times do correspond properly.  In Lightworks, I'm playing the video in a display window for the clip, in order to make a subclip containing the section of video to use for my first cut. I've also noticed that the video displayed in Lightworks is a number of seconds shorter.

Why is this happening? [Can't get audio and video speeds to play at original speeds](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/16427/cant-get-audio-and-video-speeds-to-play-at-original-speeds) seems like it may be related, but I'm unsure if the audio is playing at the proper speed because I haven't figured out how to make Lightworks make sound.  In any case, the only answer to that question just recommends changing the audio speed, which won't resolve my issue.

Do I need to recode my footage for use with Lightworks?  What are the proper settings?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is that your Lightworks project framerate setting is not the same than your clip. Did you check that ?

Comment: I didn't make it that far because it sounded like it didn't apply to looking at clips in the viewer, only to clips that had been imported into the timeline (sorry if that's not what Lightworks calls it).

Comment: Also it looks like my project framerate is set to 24fps which is completely different from the video framerate which is close to 30fps